# Template is not refreshing on object property change (Ember 2)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm running into an issue with Ember where when I change a property of an object (in this case filteredHeroes) and then set the computed property to be the updated version, my template does not update. How can I force the template to update with the change to the object when the action is called?

In my template, I have:

```
{{#each filteredHeroes as |hero index|}}
{{hero._data.AttacksPerSecond}}
{{/each}}
```

In my controller I have an action:

```
calculateStats() {
        var heroes = this.get("filteredHeroes");

        var valueOfAttackSpeedPerCP = 5.5;
        var valueOfPowerPerCP = 6;

        var attackSpeed = this.get('cpAttackSpeed') * valueOfAttackSpeedPerCP;
        var power = this.get('cpPower') * valueOfPowerPerCP;

        for (var i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
            //Set Attacks per second for the specific hero
            heroes[i]._data.AttacksPerSecond = (1 / (heroes[i]._data.attributesByLevel[14]['BaseAttackTime'] / ((heroes[i]._data.attributesByLevel[14]['AttackSpeedRating'] + attackSpeed) / 100)));   
        }
        this.set('filteredHeroes', heroes);
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `Ember.set(heroes[i],'_data.AttacksPerSecond', value)` only then changes will be reflected in template. you can even try notifyPropertyChange http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_notifyPropertyChange

Comment: @kumkanillam fantastic! that worked, thanks! if you post that as an answer I can accept it, otherwise I'll just post one and accept it with the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) then we need to use `get` and `set` method so that changes will be reflected in template and will trigger the corresponding computed properties and observers.
For array manipulation, you need to use methods available [Ember.NativeArray](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html)

If you are not sure about the object whether its normal object or `Ember.Object`, then you can always use [`Ember.Set`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_set) so that changes will be observed by template,computed properties and observer.

Comment: I had to use Ember.set(heroes[i],'_data.AttacksPerSecond', value) to change the one property instead of setting the full object